# Meteor events target behaving strange on links with inner icons

Tags: javascript, events, meteor

Folks, I am confused with Meteor's event targets: Let's say I have two links, one with an icon (here: Font Awesome) inside, one with a simple "x" instead:

**myTemplate.html**

```
<a href="#" id="linkA" data-id="link"><i data-id="icon" class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></a>
<a href="#" id="linkB" data-id="link">x</a>
```

and I am using a click event on each, both events are just the same:

**myTemplate.js**

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    'click #linkA': function(event,template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.getAttribute("data-id"));
    },
    'click #linkB': function(event,template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.getAttribute("data-id"));
    }
}
```

then I would expect them both to behave just the same. Instead, linkA's event gives me "icon" to the console, which is the data-id of the icon, and linkB's event brings me "link" to the console, which is the data-id of the link. I would expect the latter for both.

Any ideas what causes this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what we have here is event bubbling. It's javascript issue, not meteor's.

In the first case, you actually click `<i>` element, and that event is bubbling to its parents, and since `#linkA` parent has click handler it logs event.target (which is `<i>`) data-id attribute.

You can read more about this [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

Comment: Just found out that this has been fixed in Meteor long time ago and is well documented under http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps, facepalm for myself ;)

Comment: @MoritzWalter What do you mean that it has been 'fixed'? This is how javascript works ;-) In your case just use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`

Comment: so currentTarget isn't Meteor specific?

Comment: absolutely no! whole `event` object isn't meteor's at all. [mdn event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.currentTarget)

Comment: ok, it totally makes sense now! this was really a black hole in my knowledge, i did not know about nested events and event bubbling before. Thanks a lot for the hints!

Answer (score 4):

Use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target` and it'll work, and learn how to deal with nested events and event bubbling